# Set a hosts file definition only for certain applications?

Tags: windows, dns, hosts

I can set redirection to localhost by modifying my hosts file but this is a global modification.

Is there a way to redirect DNS resolution on a per-application basis?

Acceptable solutions include writing a launcher application which calls Win32 API before executing the target program as a child process.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to provide alternate DNS settings for a specific application in native windows.

There are some non-native ways to do this.

- You can modify the application to incorporate its own resolver and resolver settings. For example, there are some Firefox plugins that do this.
- You can use containerization like Docker to slide a layer of indirection between your special application and your real kernel. Effectively you are fiddling with most of the OS dependent calls. This would include abstracting the system resolver. I'm not sure exactly how Docker does this on Windows.
- You can use full blown VMs to do the same as previous, but it's much more setup work.

I'm not sure what exactly you are suggesting by calling Win32 API. If you are suggesting loading alternate dynamic linked libraries, this does not work because the resolver is a system resource, not a library. There is no simple way to get a shim between an application and its dependency on the system resolver.